# JAVA UUID use only numeric characters to generate random UUID

Tags: java, random, uuid

I want to generate a serial number for one of my classes like `xxxxxxxxxx` and I want its length to be exactly 10 characters.

how can I generate random UUID by only using `"1234567890"`.
is there something I have to pass to `constructor` or `UUID.randomUUID()`?

and how can I give it a fixed length?

Comment: In addition, look at `String.format` to format an integer (such as a `long`) into a 10-digit string.

Comment: actually, I want to use ```UUID``` class for some specific methods I can use.

Comment: If you limit the format of a UUID to 10 digits, then it's not a UUID anymore; see [RFC 4122](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4122).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) gives [128 bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/128-bit_computing), where the range of 10 digits is about 33 bits, using 2<sup>10</sup> is approx. 10<sup>3</sup>. So the uniqueness is reduced.

One can do something like:

```
String randomCode() {
    UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    long lo = uuid.getLeastSignificantBits();
    long hi = uuid.getMostSignificantBits();
    lo = (lo >> (64 - 31)) ^ lo;
    hi = (hi >> (64 - 31)) ^ hi;
    String s = String.format("%010d", Math.abs(hi) + Math.abs(lo));
    return s.substring(s.length() - 10);
}
```

This folds the 128 bits almost 4 fold to deliver 10 digits.
That is as said not necessarily unique.

It might be better to use a secret pseudo-random sequence, requiring saving a state. Or any of the other random generators / System.nanos().

Comment: The range of 10 decimal digits is about 33 bits

Comment: @saka1029 of course. Changed code.